# Store all data to 2D array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save login credentials to HTML table (be patient please, I'm not a professional). I'm using push method to store the data but eventually, it stores only data of the last iteration because it was built around click function. So my question is how I store all credentials and not only the last one

```
<body>
<form name="login" class="diss">
Username<input type="text" name="userid" id="userName" />
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd" id="passw"/>
<input type="button" class="btn-dis"  value="Login"/> 
</form>
<table id="showAfter">
<tr>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>Password</th>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="firstMission.js"></script>
</body>

document.querySelector('.btn-dis').addEventListener('click', function() 
x = document.getElementById("userName").value;
y = document.getElementById("passw").value;
table=document.getElementById('showAfter');
if (x=='' || y ==''){
    alert("no can do");
    restart();
}
else{
    myTestArr.push([x,y]);

    for(var i=0;i<myTestArr.length;i++)
    {               

        var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
        for(var j=0;j<myTestArr[i].length;j++)
        {
            var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
            cell.innerHTML=myTestArr[i][j];

        }
    }
}
mySecArr[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myTestArr[i])); //copying to another 
 array 
myTestArr.pop();   
});
```

Comment: Where have you declared myTestArr as an array?

Comment: input type="button" might be submitting the form - so the page could be loading fresh each time.

Comment: Wondering why you are doing pop later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you are going for here. But, given what I think you want, the following implementation will allow you to add new usernames and passwords to a table, while simultaneously storing them into an array.

```js
const credentials = [];
document.querySelector('.btn-dis').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let user = document.querySelector("#userName").value,
    pass = document.querySelector("#passw").value,
    table = document.querySelector("#showAfter");
  if (!user && !pass) {
    alert("no can do")
  } else {
    credentials.push([user, pass]);
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = user;
    cell = newRow.insertCell(1);
    cell.innerHTML = pass;
  }

})
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="login" class="diss">
    Username<input type="text" name="userid" id="userName" /> Password
    <input type="password" name="pswrd" id="passw" />
    <input type="button" class="btn-dis" value="Login" />
  </form>
  <table id="showAfter">
    <tr>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Password</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

That being said, saving credentials to memory is generally a bad practice, one which i would not recommend doing. But given you are a beginner, i'm going to make the assumption that this is for learning purposes only.